# Why does \usepackage{tgadventor} change the width of my bold text?

Tags: fonts, bold

I want to use the `texgyreadventor` font in PdfLaTeX and found the `tgadventor` package. When I include it, it makes my sans sherif text look like expected. However, the inclusion of the font also reduces the spacing for regular bold text, making it look more like fakebold, which is an unintended side effect.

When I have `\usepackage{tgadventor}` in my preamble:

[image: with \usepackage{tgadventor}]

When I remove `\usepackage{tgadventor}` from my preamble the bold text looks like it should:

[image: without \usepackage{tgadventor}]

I tried with another sans sherif font package (comicneue), which did not exhibit the same behavior. Changing away from PdfLaTeX is not an option for me.

If this is a bug, any pointers on where to report it would also be appreciated.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tgadventor}
\begin{document}
\textsf{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet} (only the sans sherif text should be affected by inclusion of the tgadventor font)\\ 
\textbf{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works fine on a current tex system. But the package redefines \bfdefault and this has this effect in older tex systems. Add `\renewcommand\bfdefault{bx}` or update your tex system.

Comment: I'm using TeXLive 2019 through overleaf, which is the newest available there, but the command works. Do you want to post it as an answer so I can mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tgadventor changes the default bf series. In older latex versions you then get this effect. You can set the `\bfdefault` back to bx like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tgadventor}
\renewcommand\bfdefault{bx}
\begin{document}
\textsf{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet} (only the sans sherif text should be affected by inclusion of the tgadventor font)\\ 
\textbf{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
\end{document}
```

This is not needed one a current `LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5`!.

`\textsf{\textbf{bold sans serif}}` will then produce such warnings:

```
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/qag/bx/n' in size <10> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/qag/b/n' tried instead on input line 35.
```

You can safely ignore them, the substitution is fine.